# Concatenating files from a directory using cat gives "No such file or directory" error

Tags: directory, cat

I have some files in a directory A.
From another directory B, I want to concatenate them in one single file.
I use the command line `cat` like `cat path_A/* > my_file_output`

I have an error that say `No such file or directory`

```
cat /data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]/Train/* > nbF50_train.fasta
cat: '/data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]/Train/*': No such file or directory
```

When I enter the directory A. and execute either

```
cat * > my_file_output`
```

or

```
cat * > path_B/my_file_output
```

it works fine.

But I want

```
cat path_A/* > my_file_output
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are there literal []s in the directory names?  If so, the shell is expanding it as an expansion.

Comment: @jsbillings , yes, one folder in the path is **nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]** that contains indeed the **[]** in it. Beside renaming the folder name, how can I solve this issue, because i have lot off folder like this **nbF-var_i_nbSeqs-[min-max]** where var_i, min and max are integers. Thanks.

Comment: You can also do something like `find /data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/ -type f -exec cat {} >> ~/results.txt \;` if you know they are all text files you need.

Comment: @cutrightjm , thank you for your suggestion. In my case, I can't use find, because there are a lot of folders (as I explain in my previous comment) that contain similar files.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since you are just wildcard catting anyways. Just run find on the folder you are wanting to concatenate everything in. If you don't want to go deeper, set maxdepth.

Comment: @cutrightjm , your method work fine thanks.  In fact, in my previous comment, I am based on your code  `find /data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/ -type f -exec cat {} >> ~/results.txt \;` wich contain only the first part of the path `/data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/` , from here I have many folders with the name look like *nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]* that contains similar files, for that i said it will not work for me. But Now I tested it with the whole path `find /data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]/Train -type f -exec cat {} >> results_2.txt \;` and it work fine. thanks.

Comment: @cutrightjm , you can add your response as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must either escape your `[` and `]` to `\[` and `\]` or put the path in quotes to prevent these globs to expand, make sure to keep the `*` out of the quotes:

```bsh
cat '/data/chei2402/ibra/test_infernal/nbF-050_nbSeqs-[20-40]/Train/'* > nbF50_train.fasta
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I have tried putting the whole path in quotes, but it didn't work, because of *. **So your sentence "make sure to keep the * out of the quotes" is very very important for me**.